# Why does scope resolution fail in presence of decltype?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

It is my understanding that decltype is used to query the type of an objects/variables and so on.

From the examples present on wikipedia, such as the following:

```
int i;
decltype(i) x3; // type is int
```

I assumed I could do something like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    int a, b;
};

template<typename T>
struct IsClass
{
    enum { Yes = std::is_class<T>::value };
    enum { No = !Yes };
};

std::vector<A> v;
auto it = v.begin();
IsClass<decltype(it)::value_type>::Yes
```

Because after all this line is legal:

```
IsClass<std::vector<A>::iterator::value_type>::Yes
```

Alas it wouldn't compile, citing the following: `error C2039: 'value_type' : is not a member of '`global namespace''`

Any ideas as to why scope resolution was made to behave this way in presence of decltype?

P.S: If it makes any difference I'm using MSVC2012 (*without* the Nov CTP)

Comment: `gcc` and `clang` seem to accept this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=bc884ca6b1f51d36c231f2eb08dec3ad-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I just pasted this into MSVC2012 which I'm using (I added a note to this effect) and it does not compile.

Comment: MSVC does suck though, they haven't made the same progress implementing the standard as gcc and clang

Comment: This compiles though: `IsClass<std::remove_reference<decltype(it)>::type::value_type>::Yes;` My guess is that although it should be a value type, MSVC incorrectly yields a reference type here for `decltype(it)`.

Comment: It is a know issue. Try `typedef decltype(it) itType` and then use it.

Comment: Did you #include <type_traits> ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known bug in the Visual C++ compiler.  It has not yet been fixed as of the Visual C++ 2013 Preview.  You can work around this issue using `std::common_type`:

```
IsClass<std::common_type<decltype(it)>::type::value_type>::Yes
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^^
```

(`std::common_type` with a single template argument yields that argument type; it's the standardized C++11 equivalent of the `identity` template that has long been used in metaprogramming.)

You can find the public bug report on Microsoft Connect:  [Cannot use decltype before scope operator](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/757545/cannot-use-decltype-before-scope-operator).  If this issue is important to you, please consider upvoting that bug report.

Comment: Still don't understand why they couldn't call it `std::identity`. Y'know, like everybody else.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: There was an `std::identity` before, but it's been removed because it was unclear what exactly it should be (Just meta-programming identity, like `std::common_type<T>` is now? Functional identity?), IIRC.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: It doesn't look like a matter of what to "call" it. The functionality of `std::common_type` is wider than that of `std::identity`. It simply covers `std::identity` as well. So the question was really whether to keep `std::identity` as something with a prettier name or to remove it as something redundant. They removed it.

Comment: @AndreyT: Yeah, good point. Still, I wouldn't have minded a template typedef because, as it is now, I find myself having to _explain_ what `std::common_type` with a single argument does. James had to. `std::identity` would be pretty self-explanatory in that everybody was already using that name for the same meaning.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  In addition to the "let's not add extraneous things" argument, `identity` already had another meaning, in [the original STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/identity.html).  I agree though, it would have been nice if there was an `std::identity`.  It would indeed make things simpler to explain.

Comment: @James: Ah, the STL argument clinches it. Bastards!