# decltype and member type

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to get the member type after `decltype` and define a variable `y`.

```
struct s
{
    typedef int val_type;
};

int main()
{
    s x;
    decltype(x)::val_type y;
}
```

In the above program, the Microsoft VS2013 preview c++ compiler complains:

```
'val_type' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
```

However, `decltype(x)` does get type `s`. Why couldn't I follow `val_type` after it to get the member type?

Comment: [Works in Clang 3.4](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8219c23125f144657b88d4b99a457f7c-24b1833cd2ae4d8d0edfea488a7bb6ba) [and GCC 4.8.1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8219c23125f144657b88d4b99a457f7c-3afcc3bc1f2cd10b247c33a6cde9edad).

Comment: It looks like he's using microsoft's compiler, judging from how the error is formatted.

Comment: Yes, I am using VS2013 preview.

Comment: [Pretty similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499417/why-does-scope-resolution-fail-in-presence-of-decltype)

Comment: Works on Apple LLVM 4.2 (which is basically clang, so no shock there).

Comment: Side note which may or may not be useful to you: You can quite easily [install GCC 4.8 on Windows via MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/). Just add the path to the installed bin/ to your  %PATH% and you can compile from the command line :-) Of course, you lose the VS integration and intellisense in this case...