# Why Can't I Get the bool Value from a value_type Returned by decltype?

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, metaprogramming, value-type, decltype

This appears to be a [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio) problem. This code [runs fine in gcc](http://ideone.com/vnn5nX) but fails to compile in Visual Studio:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

true_type foo();

template <typename T>
struct bar{
    using def = conditional_t<decltype(foo())::value, char, void>;
};

int main() {
     cout << typeid(bar<int>::def).name() << endl;

     cout << decltype(foo())::value << endl;
}
```

The error given is:

> error C2146: syntax error: missing `>` before identifier `value`

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://rextester.com/DKQRC22953)

Is there a bug fix for this or a workaround?

Comment: What compiler do you use? (seems to work on [gcc 6.1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69fbf1c430cf3e1a))

Comment: @milleniumbug Unfortunately I'm on Visual Studio which appears to have a bug :(

Comment: Here are some older questions about using the scoping operator directly with decltype: [decltype and the scope operator in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291336/decltype-and-the-scope-operator-in-c) and [Why does scope resolution fail in presence of decltype?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499417/why-does-scope-resolution-fail-in-presence-of-decltype).  Seems that this is valid now, but Microsoft still doesn't support it.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles Yeah I reported it as a bug. Seems like it's actually making the `struct` a `template` that triggers it, unfortunately I need the template.

Comment: I'm not sure if it can help you, but I am able to work around the problem like this: First define: `template <typename I> using id = I;`  Then replace every instance of `decltype(foo())::value` with `id<decltype(foo())>::value`.  It's strange that the `cout` line seems to compile, but the `using def = ...` triggers the error.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles Yup, it looks like the act of splitting the `decltype` out of the `conditional_t` fixes things. `using id = decltype(foo()); using def = conditional_t<id::value, char, void>;` That's a great workaround. Care to post an answer?

Comment: Ok, now that your question is no longer "on hold" I'll copy my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it can help you, but I am able to work around the problem like this:

First define:

```
template <typename I> using id = I;
```

Then replace every instance of `decltype(foo())::value` with

```
id<decltype(foo())>::value
```

Alternately, you could use `std::common_type_t` the same way:

```
std::common_type_t<foo()>::value
```

Or, my psychic powers predict you might just want to define a separate type for `decltype<foo()>`, for convenience:

`using id = decltype(foo());`

then replace all instances of `decltype(foo())::value` with `id::value`.

Answer (score 2):

In your question you're using `decltype(foo())`:

```
using def = conditional_t<decltype(foo())::value, char, void>;
                                   ^^^^^
```

while on Ideone, `decltype(foo)`:

```
using def = conditional_t<decltype(foo)::value, char, void>;
                                  ^^^^^
```

They're different things. In the first case, you're getting the type of *the result of calling `foo`*. In the second one you're getting the type *of a function itself*.

---

Okay, since that time things changed dramatically.

The code was edited and was supposed to compile well, but compilations with Visual Studio were failing, while clang was very happy with this code and wasn't showing any errors and even warnings.

So, given that clang (the latest version, using `--std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra`) finds this code correct, I believe this should be *a bug in VS*.

Comment: @JonathanMee, this compiles well using C++14 standard. Although I don't know how do we change standards in VS...

Comment: Did you try the code that I posted on Visual Studio 2015? I posted a link to Microsoft's Web Compiler. It does *not* compile well.

Comment: @JonathanMee, yeah, I tried it there and it didn't compile. Then I compiled this with `clang --std=c++11` and it complained that it couldn't find `conditional_t`, so I compiled with `--std=c++14` and it worked well without any warnings. So I thought it could be possible to specify the language standard in VS, but didn't find anything useful online. I think this is a bug in VS. You may want to try MinGW or MinGW64 instead, I find the latter very good while MinGW may be a bit outdated.

Comment: Maybe you could add that to your answer, cause as of now it points out a typographical error that I did have but was not in fact my issue.